# Create data for testing MongoDB and Postgresql

Tags: mongodb, postgresql, database

I need to test the performance of MongoDB and Postgresql in large amount of data, over 5GB, for a college's assignment.
How can I create data for both databases?
Thanks

EDIT:
I found this webpage http://www.generatedata.com where you can download a script to generate the data

Comment: We'll need a little more detail. What sort of data? Is it about people? Payments? Usage? What are you going to do with it?

Comment: The data is not really important... I only need several tables, some of them with foreign keys and very large amount of rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First,  take a look to [How to Generate Test Data on MongoDB](http://dws.la/how-to-generate-test-data-on-mongodb/). For MongoDB [mongoperf](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoperf/) i a tool to measure performance of such database on disk. also, you can see [MongoDB Benchmarks](https://blog.serverdensity.com/mongodb-benchmarks/). For Postgressql you can use [pgbench](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/pgbench.html).